# how to find element using jquery element

Tags: jquery

Here is the scenario

```
doc = $('<div><h1>hello</h1><div>')
ele = $('<h1>hello</h1>') or ele = doc.find('h1').clone()
doc.find(ele)
```

doesn't produce any result..

Comment: It doesn’t find anything, because your `ele` is not the _same_ element as the `h1` element inside your `doc`. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @CBroe That's exactly what the posted answer says.

Comment: @CBroe I know those element are the same element. My question how would you achieve it when an element is cloned...

Comment: If one is a clone, then they are not the same element.

Comment: why downvote the question even before understanding what the questions..may be I am missed entering some details..doesn't mean it has to be down voted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm adding a second answer since the two answers are very different)

An alternative is to define your own `clone` method which keeps a record of which element was cloned from.

```
jQuery.fn.cloneWithRecord = function() {
  var clone = jQuery(this).clone();
  clone.data('clone-parent', this);
  return clone;
}
var doc = jQuery('<div><h1>hello</h1><div>');
var ele = doc.find('h1').cloneWithRecord();

ele.data('clone-parent') // => [<h1>hello</h1>] from doc
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the output you see is the *expected* result. `$.find` will look for the exact same element. When you clone an element, it is no longer the exact same element.

Here is a long workaround that isn't really performant, but may be what you need:

```
doc.find(ele[0].nodeName).filter(function(){return this.outerHTML == ele[0].outerHTML})
// returns the element [<h1>hello</h1>] in `doc`
```

Comment: It's not quite the same, because `.find()` searches all levels, but `.children` only searches the next level down.

Comment: ok I updated the answer to use `find` and also reduce the search space. Also ".find() searches all levels" is incorrect, it does not search the root level.